# SQL Rows to Columns if column values are unknown

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that has demographic information about a set of users which looks like this:

```
User_id   Category IsMember
1         College     1
1         Married     0
1         Employed    1
1         Has_Kids    1
2         College     0
2         Married     1
2         Employed    1
3         College     0
3         Employed    0
```

The result set I want is a table that looks like this:

```
User_Id|College|Married|Employed|Has_Kids
1            1        0        1        1
2            0        1        1        0
3            0        0        0        0
```

In other words, the table indicates the presence or absence of a category for each user.  Sometimes the user will have a category where the value if false, sometimes the user will have no row for a category, in which case IsMember is assumed to be false.

Also, from time to time additional categories will be added to the data set, and I'm wondering if its possible to do this query without knowing up front all the possible category names, in other words, I won't be able to specify all the column names I want to count in the result.  (Note only user 1 has category "has_kids" and user 3 is missing a row for category "married"

(using Postgres)

Thanks.

Comment: You probably need to use a `pivot` with dynamic sql. I'm not sure of the postgres syntax for this, so I'm not submitting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jsonb funcions.

```
with titles as (
 select jsonb_object_agg(Category, Category) as titles,
        jsonb_object_agg(Category, -1) as defaults
   from demog
),
the_rows as (
select null::bigint as id, titles as data
  from titles
union
select User_id, defaults || jsonb_object_agg(Category, IsMember)
  from demog, titles
  group by User_id, defaults
)
select id, string_agg(value, '|' order by key)
  from (
    select id, key, value
      from the_rows, jsonb_each_text(data)
  ) x
  group by id
  order by id nulls first
```

You can see a running example in http://rextester.com/QEGT70842

You can replace `-1` with `0` for the default value and `'|'` with `','` for the separator.

Answer (score 0):

You can install tablefunc module and use the crosstab function.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html

Comment: Thanks.  I am hosted on Heroku, not sure if I have a lot of options to modify the server like that.

Comment: As it turns out Heroku does let you install tablefunc, but crosstab requires that you specify the names of the columns  you want in the crosstab, which defeats the purpose, as over time I want to add new categories without having to rewrite the code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a Postgres function script called **colpivot** [here](https://github.com/hnsl/colpivot/blob/master/colpivot.sql) which does the trick.  Ran the script to create the function, then created the table in one statement:

```
select colpivot ('_pivoted', 'select * from user_categories', array['user_id'],
             array ['category'], '#.is_member',  null);
```